# Joomla Jtable error

Tags: jtable, joomla3.0

I am getting  the following error **"Error500: JTableUser::bind(*NULL*)"**, when try to send value from fieldset to database by click to submit button.

My save function in model looks like this:

```
public function save($data)
    {
        $userId = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : (int) $this->getState('user.id');

        $user = new JUser($userId);

        JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'tables');
        $table =& JTable::getInstance('User', 'JTable', array());

        // Unset the username so it does not get overwritten
        unset($data['username']);

        // Unset the block so it does not get overwritten
        unset($data['block']);

        // Unset the sendEmail so it does not get overwritten
        unset($data['sendEmail']);

        // Bind the data.
        if (!$table->bind($data)) {
            $this->setError(JText::sprintf('USERS PROFILE BIND FAILED', $user->getError()));
            return false;
        }

        // Load the users plugin group.
        JPluginHelper::importPlugin('user');

        // Null the user groups so they don't get overwritten
        $user->groups = null;

        // Store the data.
        if (!$table->save()) {
            $this->setError($user->getError());
            return false;
        }

        return $user->id;
    }`
```

$data is filled correctly, `"getInstance('User', 'JTable', array());"` works okay. 
Thank you for attention, could anybody help me with my trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late reply, but I think the issue is in the line:

```
if (!$table->save())
```

since the save method in JTable (3.2) expects the bind data as the 1st parameter, and it's not getting anything.

Since you've bound the data previously, you probably want:

```
if (!$table->store())
```

http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JTable.html#method_save